# New freelance web developer, realistic goals and expectations?

Tags: job-search, salary, freelancing

I am a self-taught web developer (through premium courses where you build real apps, not just random YouTube videos), and I want to start freelancing in the near future.

**My background:**

My skills so far include the MERN stack, jQuery & vanilla JS, and of course, HTML & CSS (including SASS and LESS)

My real experience is currently not very rich, I only have 4 static sites I built for people/companies from my environment, 3 of which were built long time ago with just HTML, CSS and vanilla JS, the 4th one is built with GatsbyJS.

However I am in the process of building several concepts (basically fake apps) to show the stuff I can do now, including a very simple social media app, an e-commerce website, a simple chat app with WebSockets, and a one page app using somebody else's API.

**My question:**

With the skills listed above, I want to know how difficult is finding jobs going to be, and even more importantly, how much can I expect to earn in the beginning?

I'm not asking for the first month necessarily, since I know every beginning is hard, and it's more about finding your place, but maybe 2-3 months in?

I live in a pretty poor country, so if I could reach 1000$ per month, it would improve my life significantly, but I don't know is that a realistic goal for now. Of course, that's not where my ambitions end, I intend on learning much more, but for now I could use both the experience and the money from what I already know.

And I know freelancing is not a company job, so it's all relative, but I should have enough of free time, and I'm willing to put in the work necessary, so consider me an enthusiastic newbie I guess?

Either way, I'd like to hear your thoughts and experiences, I know virtually no other web developers in real life, so I want to get a realistic image of what it's like, so I can adjust my goals and plans accordingly.

Thank you for your time, hope someone can help!

Comment: "With the skills listed above, I want to know how difficult is finding jobs going to be, and even more importantly, how much can I expect to earn in the beginning?" Neither of those are questions we can answer here. I wish it was that easy that in 2 paragraph we can guess someones employability and value, but the real world of hiring is never that simple. What you likely want to do is pick up the phone/open email client and try to get some clients, see what sticks. Keep in mind that there are literally millions of other people doing the same in most poor countries, try to find them and ask.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know people can't guess that stuff by just reading a few sentences, but I was just wondering is it possible theoretically to earn some decent money with my current skillset. Then if in practice it turns out I suck, that's my own problem and I know what to work on. I'd like to be able to at least have a realistic goal someone in my position could strive for.

Comment: Again, we don't know if you will manage to make 1k usd or not. Many do not, many do a lot more and this question will be closed soon as this is not not answerable, simple as that. If you got nothing else to do with time, there is little harm from picking up the phone.

Answer (score 3):

Freelancing is all about networking and experience. So it's best to work a normal job first, gain a reputation and some contacts and then try freelancing.

No one wants to put their money on someone they don't know who has no experience. Being self taught and from a poor country is not an asset. The overseas people who will hire you are looking for cheap work for simple projects. They're not usually return customers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, regular job is not an option, since my current health situation is less than ideal.

I do understand that people want someone with experience, but I can't force people to hire me, I am looking for a strategy that would help me get more jobs and build that.

Comment: Get qualified locally and build a professional network. Ideally local is your best market. A lot of poor countries have very few skilled IT people because they don't have the training resources, and don't pay enough to attract professionals from outside. Most of the IT professionals in my country would be considered rubbish overseas but have built whole careers here.

Answer (score 1):

Freelancing takes time to build reputation.

You can register on sites like freelancer, Upwork, Toptal etc and start bidding on projects.
You can choose what projects to bid on and what price to set, usually within bounds pre-set for the project.

From what i have seen, there are plethora of skill-sets and different levels of proficiency required.

Beware of projects that clearly under priced or depict illegal activities.

One BIG suggestion, do not accept any project you do not know how to complete, reputation on these websites is very important, due to high competition.

Occasionally, freelancers get pretty steady stream of assignments from one time customer following initial project

Good luck

Comment: Do note that mentioning upwork and toptal (or 10x) in the same sentence, is like casually mentioning a $5,000 sedan and a $500,000 veyron in a sentence "Why not buy a car?" - !

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I was planning on registering on freelance sites, yes, but I'd like to be prepared and have a good strategy, which is why I'm here first.

Comment: @Fattie nice metaphor, wrong sentience. Mention of these cars was in a sentience - "what types of cars out there", and not what to purchase. Extending on your metaphor - OP post is about getting a license and learning to drive

Comment: @Strader- for sure, just to be completely clear the typical job price on freelancer/upwork is 50 to 500 bucks; toptal and 10x deal with 6- and 7- figure projects.  do note that the OP absolutely can not "register" on toptal (or 10x) !  the OP can and should sign on to freelancer/upwork and try to get some work.

Comment: @Fattie In applicating to OPs current status, I agree. But, lets say, Toptal, is something that OP can strive for and see freelancer / Upwork or any other platform that may arise, as a stepping stone toward the goal and not the only place he can get work

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer since it's very relative. Some clients want relatively quick and easy changes, but for some reason don't already have a developer... but those will either be automation jobs (Python / PHP scripting) or WordPress related. You might get a few jobs fixing broken projects, but those won't be easy (as another developer has already dug themselves into a corner and now you have two problems). I think the real problem is that your skillset doesn't easily lend itself to quick projects unless you have a market niche you can exploit.

You could branch out into Cordova / React Native development (since you know React), which would open a lot more options for you. I'm assuming that by Apps, you mean web-apps that run on a browser?

In my experience what really nails freelancers down is that the ability to get paid is a completely separate skill from their programming ability; it's too easy to be a great developer but also very broke; and Upwork and their related sites help contribute to that, since their systems are explicitly set up to prevent you from taking your reputation and clients with you and they force you to compete on price as well as making you pay for that privilege.

I'd be happy to advise on this further if you reply with an email you're reachable at.

The short answer though is that finding your first job is likely to be very, very hard, especially if you're doing it over the internet. As to how much you "can" make, if you're good a contract developer can charge $150 per hour, you could pull a thousand a day with the right client. Though the real questions are "What kind of problems can you solve for that client with the skills you have?" and "How do I make the client aware that I can solve their problems?".

Comment: The OP should be aware that it is utterly, utterly, utterly inconceivable the OP could make the serious money mentioned at the end of this answer, within say **10 years** from now.  As has been said 1000 times on this site, programmers make insanely high pay.  But - to do so you have to have a **gold-plated list of household name products** you have done (and indeed have spectacular technical knowledge).

Comment: The point made in my answer is that it's entirely possible to make that money if you have skills that people need and a way to convey to them that they need your skills. The dynamic between freelancers and their clients is very different than an employer and an employee. EDIT: To expand on that, I've never had a client ask for my credentials or even seem very interested in other projects I've done except in a very general way, they're often not technical and can't really evaluate freelancers, that's why they're getting a professional (you) to run their project.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, as mentioned, I can learn practical skills and coding itself, but that's about it, I am clueless about how this world works.

Now I feel like I may have been wasting my time, since the stuff I read on the internet make it sound like I will never get any job. 

My email is jon.carter.83@yahoo.com, you can reach me there, I'd definitely appreciate more insight into this whole topic, as mentioned in the question, I have nobody to ask in real life

Comment: @CarterJ It looks like that email doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, it's without the second dot, so jon.carter83@yahoo.com

Answer (score -1):

For the sake of an answer,

1. It looks like you've taken an **admirable first step** in www development. It is realistic to say you have a long way to go.  Keep learning - very hard.
2. Note that, and this has been said many times on the site, unfortunately "nobody cares" about self-made example projects. By all means keep doing them for your learning.
3. The fact that you are in an out-of-the-way country, is no problem at all.
4. Do note that in programming, **it is very hard to get that "first job"**. (Or, if you want to do little freelance jobs, those first little projects.) This is the overwhelming reality of programming.  It's actually very easy to learn the basics ("anyone can do it") so there is a vast amount of competition at low levels.

> "so I want to get a realistic image of what it's like, so I can adjust my goals and plans accordingly"

It is very hard to "break in", and there is a vast amount of people trying their hand at low levels.

You might as well put up an ad on freelancer or upwork, and try your hand! And search locally for folks who need www.  Good luck!

## Your local tip ...

Remember you have a **HUGE advantage in your local country**. Today, send out 100 emails to businesses in your city, your country, that may need some web site action. It does not matter what rate you get at first to "get your foot in the door".

**If you are shy, you won't succeed!**  So don't be shy. I strongly suggest in your local city, hand out a simple flyer (just print it out) for your services. Aim to do this by 2pm your time Monday. Even if absolutely nothing comes of it, your growth in business will be assured. It need be this simple

```
-----------------
| Johnnie Jones |
|LOCAL and CHEAP|
|  web services |
| www problems? |
|  need www?    |
|Johnnie gets it|
|done 2558018223|
|---------------|
```

It's that easy - don't overthink it. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 

I was planning to put up an ad on one of those sites, yes, but I'd like to go there prepared, and hopefully achieve the best results possible for someone in my position. 

If self-made example projects are worthless, what would be a good alternative to get people to hire you? And as for "long way to go", I already did say I plan on moving forward, but is it possible that everything I learned so far is next to worthless? I've heard of people earning decent money after a few months of learning, I invested a lot more, but now I feel useless anyway

Comment: I would urge you to go ahead and put up an ad today.  it makes no difference at all, if, later you completely change your "ad".  Enjoy!

Comment: You have PLENTY of skills to get small jobs on upwork/freelancer - GO FOR IT

Comment: Alright, thank you, I will try it

Comment: No reason you can't succeed!  Good luck!  I will put a LOCAL TIP in the answer ..